# Why does using WindowMenuBarExtraStyle make components unresponsive?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to create a SwiftUI macOS system menu bar app with a `Toggle` for enabling/disabling its behavior. Things work as expected using the default `PullDownMenuBarExtraStyle`, but I would like to use `WindowMenuBarExtraStyle` to allow me to add e.g. a `TextInput` later. However, when I do so, the toggle becomes stuck in the `true` state and doesn't respond to clicks.

What am I missing here?

This works as expected:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var isOn = true

    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("MyApp") {
            Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $isOn)
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the `Toggle` is unresponsive:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var isOn = true

    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("MyApp") {
            Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $isOn)
        }.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scene contains the view hierarchy of your app, not your views. I would propose to put `Toggle` and your variable in a separate view structure.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("MyApp") {
            MenuBarView()
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
}
```

Then build the menu bar window:

```
struct MenuBarView: View {
    @State private var isOn = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $isOn)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Can you expand on why this is necessary?